# how split and convert string?

Tags: c#, string, split

Im start learning c# and have this specific question, hope some body can reply this:

I have this string:

```
1280,800
```

How can convert that string in this:  1280x800
Basically I imagine I have to split the string first and then +  adding "x"  string instead

So basically I think I have to split  on to variable  A B and the rebuild the string:

```
string newstring = A+"x"+B;
```

How split "1280,800" for put 1280 in a variable A and 800 in a stirng variable B ?

Please can somebody put some example for do this? I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm sure c# has a stringreplace function or similar that will replace one character with another?

Answer (score 8):

Well, an easy way would be `str = str.Replace(",", "x")`, which would replace the `,` with `x` and your ending string would be `1280x800`

or you can use

```
var temp = str.Split(",");
if (temp.Length >=2)
{
    var a = temp[0];
    var b = temp[1];
}
```

Comment: Why are you using var instead of an array of strings and strings? Is there a particular reason?

Comment: @Haedrian Because I'm a lazy programmer :) `var` is easier to type then `string[]`, and when programming I usually use `var` to avoid having to lookup return types that I've forgotten

Comment: @Haedrian var is just an easier way to type `string`, `dictionary<int,string>`, the compiler still knows it's a `string`. It does not function like the `dynamic` keyword, which allows a variable to change type.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to split the string, you could do:

```
string originalString = "1280,800";
string[] parts = originalString.Split(',');

string resultingString = parts[0] + "x" + parts[1];
```

But Rachel's suggestion of using `Replace` is the simplest way to solve the problem in question.

Answer (score 0):

This will support more commas than the other solutions (except `Replace()`).  You probably don't need it, since it looks like your working with screen resolutions, but here it is.

```
string newString = string.Join("x", "1280,800".Split(','));
```